# How to change the Rocket Chat Data Directory

Tags: ubuntu-server, rocket.chat

I have installed the Rocket Chat by following the steps provided here https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/ubuntu/snaps/

I have ubuntu server [Ubuntu 16.04.1]

To store the data [files], I would want to make use of this partition.

```
/dev/sda3      413422648   71880 392327024   1% /media/data/sd1
```

Do I have any configuration file where I can specify the storage path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to mount the new partition at the location of the data directory